# Cannot assign a value of type to type UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following error when trying to assign the value of my table to self.

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'ActivityViewController' to a value of
type 'UITableViewDataSource?'
```

---

The following lines of code are giving me the error above. I have looked on SO for other similar issues but found nothing with a table view.

```
class ActivityViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

And in my viewDidLoad function

```
table.dataSource = self
```

- I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.
- I have tried disconnecting the table from the view controller and re-connecting it as well with no luck.

---

> Full code:

```
class ActivityViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { // --> Error here

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var likersArray = [PFObject]()

    var username = ""

    func refresh() {
        var likersQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        likersArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        likersQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        likersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (likers, error) -> Void in
            if let likers = likers as? [PFObject] {
                self.likersArray = likers
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myBarColor = UIColor(red: 48/256, green: 72/256, blue: 95/256, alpha: 1.0)
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
        view.backgroundColor = myBarColor
        self.view.addSubview(view)

        refresh()

        table.dataSource = self // --> Error here


    }
```

Comment: That looks strange, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? It should work since your class definition lists the required protocol.

Comment: Tried the clean and build with no luck. I am very confused as well.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the dataSource via the interface builder?

Comment: maybe it's an issue with required datasource methods signature or maybe not all of them were implemented

Comment: can u plz post your full code where this occurs.

Comment: Full code has been posted.

Comment: implement  numberOfRowsInSection() and cellForRowAtIndexPath() and the error will disappear

Comment: can you post your `tableView()` implementation? plz

Comment: Azimov has solved this issue, could you post an answer so I give can you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because `ActivityViewController` doesn't implement required datasource methods: `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: This is a problem however would cause a "does not conform to protocol" error, rather than the "error assigning to type" message specified in the question. I've included an answer below which solves both.

Comment: "bracket issue" is mostly about a bad copy/paste :). If missing it Xcode pretty well shows where is the problem

Comment: Btw Xcode sometimes likes to cache error messages, and until a build is not performed it will show "old" error message, not very often but happens

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code which is why I think your getting these errors. Firstly there appears to be a bracket issue. Looks like your closing your class after the refresh function. Mismatching brackets can cause all kinds of strange errors.

Secondly you also need to conform to the protocol. The UITableViewDataSource protocol specifies two required functions. These are numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath. After all of this, the code should compile. Here is my version of your code, created within a playground. All appears fine on my machine. Please note, I have removed your refresh function to make things less complicated.

```
class ActivityViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var likersArray = [String]()

    var username = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myBarColor = UIColor(red: 48/256, green: 72/256, blue: 95/256, alpha: 1.0)
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
        view.backgroundColor = myBarColor
        self.view.addSubview(view)

        table.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellName", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double Check Your delegate for that you are inheriting ... I was facing the same issue because of writing UITabBarDelegate instead of UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Can you provide more background to your answer? What's the difference?

Comment: when we inherit a class from a delegate then we can use its method and properties so here when you put UITabBarDelegate or another one instead of UITableViewDelegate then you can not access the methods and properties of that delegate and will give you the error mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Welton122 should be the one considered correct, as the fundamental problem was the missing UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource parameters in the original UIViewController Class declaration.